# Create test db on same server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I know this seems like a duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676754/easiest-way-to-make-copy-sql-server-db-to-test-db), but it is not completely. I want to copy a production db (in use and critical) to another db on the same server, to allow doing some testing. What is the easiest safe way to do this ?
Here is my proposal (mostly found [here](http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/647716-sqlserver-2005-how-best-copy-one-database-another)):

```
BACKUP DATABASE srcDB TO DISK = 'D:\SQL\Data\srcDBtest.bak' WITH COPY_ONLY

RESTORE DATABASE testDB FROM DISK = 'D:\SQL\Data\srcDBtest.bak'
 WITH MOVE 'srcDB' TO 'D:\SQL\Data\testDB.mdf', 
 MOVE 'erpSql_log' TO 'D:\SQL\Data\erpsqlPH.ldf', REPLACE, STATS = 10
```

Is that going to work ? Should testDB be created before running this ? Can I use any name in the TO argument of MOVE ?

I cannot afford to make a mistake, so clarification is welcome.

Comment: Looks OK to me at first glance, but couldn't you use Management Studio instead? This stuff is a lot easier through the UI. (And if you don't already have daily backups for a production system that you could restore from instead, you should.)

Comment: @Rup: I use management studio, yes. And the idea of using an existing backup is +1 (stupid I am). After reading you, I tried right-click, restore datase, To database = testDb, From database = ProdDb...is it as simple as that ???? 8-))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the importance I would use Management Studio and follow the backup guides found on MSDN.

- For Backup follow: [How to: Back Up a
  Database (SQL Server Management
  Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx)
- For Restore follow: [How
  to: Create a New Database From an
  Existing Database Backup (SQL Server Management
  Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186390.aspx)